# Indexing methods in parse for _rperm

Tags: mongodb, indexing, acl, parse-server, compound-index

In trying to understand how Parse indexes work with Mongo, I noticed that some of my slow queries were using the `_rperm` field (from the ACL) even though I didn't specify it in the indexes that I defined. It isn't on every query either so I'm wondering why some queries need `_rperm` indexed and some don't.

If I query by just the id, the index seems to require
`{"_id": 1, "_rperm": 1}` and not just the `{"_id": 1}` index that is already defined.

What does parse do in the background to add `_rperm` and when do I need to include it as an index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the inconsistent use of the `_rperm` index is due to the use of useMasterKey in the cloud code.

If you use the master key with the query then it won't require to check the ACL. But, **if you don't use master key in your query, you will need to index the `_rperm` field on your collections** in order for that query to run efficiently.